# Updating Google Sheets Automatically

Tags: google-sheets

Multiple users are accessing the spreadsheet from one account (signed in through the email) for google sheets. Once someone adds/edits the spreadsheet, it doesn't update the other accounts due to inactivity such is causing serious problems. Is there a way to have every account update all the time? I tried google extensions but that didn't work and I do know about the recalculation "On change and every minute" but that still doesn't work. This is different to other questions because I am not pulling data from other sheets, every computer is using the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Wouldn't this issue be easily avoided by simply having the inactive users refresh the sheet before working after some time of inactivity? Once refreshed, it should update automatically on edits by other people.

Comment: @NaziA your correct, but they forget which causes major errors such as scanning over other parts. That’s why I’m wondering if there’s a way to do it automatically

Comment: From the looks of it, browser cache might be the culprit here. Try disabling offline edit for Drive and removing any drive/docs editor extensions from the browser of your users so that whenever they look at the document it will always fetch the most recent update to the Spreadsheet and when they lose connection or timedout because of memory usage, Sheets will simply not allow them to edit until it reconnects.

Comment: @HyperNinja, will accessing the sheets on a private browser/incognito be also a solution here since cache seems likely is the culprit here?

Comment: The spreadsheet already has offline edit disabled and there are no extensions attached to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you try and have them access the sheet on incognito tab? @noahfish5.